# How to bring back a far right chromeless window?

Tags: windows-7, window-manager

Accidentally some windows goes far right, and "goes out of" to the monitor. I know keyboard shortcuts to move it back when the windows have a title bar. But that windows (HTC Home and Rainlendar) don't have title bar, doesn't appears in windows TaskBar or TaskManager. I've tryed restart windows; to close and reopen that software; change the resolution to very low, and then to very high; but it doesn't works...

I know that I can dig in the settings files of that programs, but I think interesting discover how to bring back that windows so I can use that technique if that problem appears again with another softwares too.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I can't leave comments yet *eye roll* so I have to post it here.

Does your computer think it has 2 monitors? That's what it sounds like. If that is the case navigate to your Display Properties "Settings" tab, and turn it off.

Comment: That won't actually help. Disabling 2nd display won't move secondary windows.

Answer (score 1):

If the app is keeping its windows from showing up on the taskbar, it's going to be up to that app to allow you to bring them into focus. In Maya 2011, for example, I found a command under the Window menu called "Raise Application Windows". This brings those 'hidden' windows into focus, at which point I can shift them to the viewable monitor with the standard windows command keys.

Whatever program you're using, maybe you can invoke the window you can't see - even though no visible change will occur - and attempt to manipulate it in the standard way.  Hope that makes sense.